# Subtracting values from two pivot tables stored in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables:

```
df1:[1 rows x 23 columns]
                 1C   1E    1F    1H    1K ...    2M    2P    2S  2U   2W
total          1057  334  3609  3762  1393 ...   328  1611  1426  87  118

df2:[1 rows x 137 columns]
                 1CA  1CB  1CC  1CF  1CJ  1CS ...   2UB  2UJ  2WB  2WC  2WF  2WJ
total            11  381  111   20  527    2 ...    47   34   79    2    1   36
```

I need to subtract the value between two tables.
like `1C-1CF`, `1E-1EF`, `1F-1FF` and so on.

I.e I need to subtract only the column ends with `F` in sheet2.

`Answer: 1C=1C-1CF=1037`

How is this possible using Python code?

Note:

Some of ´df1´ has no ´F´ in ´df2´

```
df1:
['1C', '1E', '1F', '1H', '1K', '1M', '1N', '1P', '1Q', '1R', '1S', '1U', '1W', '2C', '2E', '2F', '2H', '2K', '2M', '2P', '2S', '2U', '2W']
df2:
['1CA', '1CB', '1CC', '1CF', '1CJ', '1CS', '1CU', '1EA', '1EB', '1EC', '1EF', '1EJ', '1ES', '1FA', '1FB', '1FC', '1FF', '1FJ', '1FS', '1FT', '1FU', '1HA', '1HB', '1HC', '1HF', '1HJ', '1HS', '1HT', '1HU', '1KA', '1KB', '1KC', '1KF', '1KJ', '1KS', '1KU', '1MA', '1MB', '1MC', '1MF', '1MJ', '1MS', '1MU', '1NA', '1NB', '1NC', '1NF', '1NJ', '1PA', '1PB', '1PC', '1PF', '1PJ', '1PS', '1PT', '1PU', '1QA', '1QB', '1QC', '1QF', '1QJ', '1RA', '1RB', '1RC', '1RF', '1RJ', '1SA', '1SB', '1SC', '1SF', '1SJ', '1SS', '1ST', '1SU', '1UA', '1UB', '1UC', '1UF', '1UJ', '1US', '1UU', '1WA', '1WB', '1WC', '1WF', '1WJ', '1WS', '1WU', '2CA', '2CB', '2CC', '2CJ', '2CS', '2EA', '2EB', '2EJ', '2FA', '2FB', '2FC', '2FJ', '2FU', '2HB', '2HC', '2HF', '2HJ', '2HU', '2KA', '2KB', '2KC', '2KF', '2KJ', '2KU', '2MA', '2MB', '2MC', '2MF', '2MJ', '2MS', '2MT', '2PA', '2PB', '2PC', '2PF', '2PJ', '2PU', '2SA', '2SB', '2SC', '2SF', '2SJ', '2UA', '2UB', '2UJ', '2WB', '2WC', '2WF', '2WJ']´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
sheet2 = sheet2.filter(regex=(".*F$"))  # Leave only 'F' columns in sheet2

sheet2.columns = [i[:-1] for i in sheet2.columns]  # Remove 'F' in the end for column-wise substraction

result = sheet1 - sheet2  # Substract values
result[result.isnull()] = sheet1  # Leave sheet1 values if there's no appropriate 'F' column in sheet2
```

**Note**: It leaves the value of `sheet1` untouched if there's no appropriate columns with 'F' in `sheet2`.

I created your dataframes like so:

```
sheet1 = pd.DataFrame({'1C': [1057], '1E': [334], '1F': [3609], '2F': [3609]})
sheet2 = pd.DataFrame({'1CA': [11], '1CB': [381], '1CC': [111], '1CF': [20], '1EF': [10], '1FF': [15]})
```

Comment: Its showing len mismatch error. `length mismatch: Expected axis has 19 elements , new values have 23 elemnets`

Comment: It works. I go with your code. its easy and providing better result

Answer (score 2):

```
sheet1_columns = sheet1.columns.tolist()
sheet2_expected_columns = ['%sF' % (c) for c in sheet1_columns]
common_columns = list(set(sheet2_expected_columns).intersection(set(sheet2.columns.tolist()))
columns_dict = {c:'%sF' % (c) for c in sheet1_columns}
sheet1_with_new_columns_names = sheet1.df.rename(columns=columns_dict)
sheet1_restriction = sheet1_with_new_columns_names[common_columns]
sheets2_restriction = sheets2[common_columns]
result = sheet1_restriction - sheet2_restriction
```

Can you test this?

Comment: last line should probably be `result = sheet1_with_new_columns - sheet2_restriction`, otherwise the subtraction won't work (there will be no matching columns between the two).

Comment: its showing that ´sheet1´ and ´sheet2´ are not defined

Comment: I think I stored sheet1 as df1 and sheet2 as df2. so I tried by changing that . but now I got "2CF,2EF,2FF,2UF" are not in index.     how can I omit those  ??

Comment: Oh ok I missed that fact, I guess you have to use a set. I changed the code to add this.

Comment: If your second sheet doesn't have a column 'xF' for **every** column 'x' in the first one, the code in the answer needs to be changed to account for that.

Comment: @julien Cochennec : Hey, thanks it worked. but a issue. It has done with the column name from sheet2: how can change that to column name with sheet1??

Comment: *how can change that to column name with sheet1??* The column renaming will need to be done on a copy of sheet2 (with a reversed dictionary). That would take some updates to most of the code sample here. I won't edit the post, though. I will let you (or the OP of the answer) get it straight - it isn't difficult.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

**Step 1:** filter the columns in df2 which have suffix `F`:

```
cols = df2.columns[df2.columns.isin([col+'F' for col in df1.columns])]
cols
Index(['1AF', '1GF'], dtype='object')
```

**Step 2:** Use string operation on `cols` and filter for `df1` dataframe, then subtract from `df2` and assign the values `df1`:

```
df1.loc[:,cols.str[:-1]] = df1[cols.str[:-1]].values - df2[cols].values
df1
        1A  1B  1C  1D  1E  1F  1G  1H  1I  1J
total   70  72  90  46  30  56  10  51  95  34
```

Values for `1A`: 82-12 = 70 and values for `1G`: 34-24=10.

Setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(30,100, size=(1,10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
df1.columns = ['1'+col for col in df1.columns]
df1.index = ['total']
df1

        1A  1B  1C  1D  1E  1F  1G  1H  1I  1J
total   82  72  90  46  30  56  34  51  95  34


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,30, size=(1,7)), columns=list('ABFGHIJ'))
df2.index = ['total']
df2.columns = ['1'+col for col in df2.columns]
df2.columns = [col+'D' for col in df2.columns]
df2.rename(columns={'1AD':'1AF','1GD':'1GF'},inplace=True)
df2
        1AF 1BD 1FD 1GF 1HD 1ID 1JD
total   12  29  29  24  10  12  17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
result_df = df1.join(df2)

for col in df1.columns:
    if ((col + 'F' in df2.columns):
        result_df[col] = result_df[col] - result_df[col + 'F']
```